# Two functions-- one on blur, and one as the model changes in Angular input field

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angular-promise, onblur

I have an AngularUI Bootstrap Typeahead. It triggers as the model changes to filter the value.

However, I also have a directive attached to this field that should trigger onBlur. The directive searches a database to check if another field is required based on the input of the typeahead field.

If I change ng-model-options to be on blur, I destroy the typeahead. If I change the directive into a function in order to use ng-blur, I can't figure out how to deal with promises and asyncValidators.

Here is my validation directive:

```
 angular.module('myApp').directive('myfieldValidation', ['$q', 'myService', function ($q, myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            ctrl.$asyncValidators.myfieldisvalidated = function (modelValue) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                myService.getdetailsofField(modelValue)
                    .then(function (response) {
                       console.log(response.data);
                       if (response.data.success == false && modelValue !== undefined && modelValue !== "") {
                            scope.launchfunction();
                            defer.reject();
                        }
                        else if (response.data.success == true) {
                            scope.Name = response.data.data["Name"];
                            scope.Number = response.data.data["Number"];
                        }
                        else {
                            defer.resolve();
                        }
                    });
                return defer.promise;
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is my typeahead input

```
 <input myfield-validation                   
                       type="text"                           
                       class="form-control"                         
                       name="namefield"
                       ng-model="namefield.namefield"
                       ng-change="otherfield = null"
                       uib-typeahead="option as option.objects for option in myList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
                       typeahead-template-url="/tpl.html"
                       typeahead-loading="loading"                           
                       typeahead-min-length="2"
                       typeahead-wait-ms="2"
                       typeahead-no-results="noResults"
                       required>
```

Is there something I can add to the directive to make it trigger on blur? I found this in another answer but I don't know how to use it.

```
element.on('blur', function () {
    if (ngModel.$dirty) {
        doServerSideValidation();
    } else {
        ngModel.$setValidity(key, true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve with your directive.  Why are you returning a promise inside the directive?  What's making use of it?

If it's server-side validation you're after, can you do this?

```
<input my-validation-directive type="text" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 700, 'blur': 0 }}" />
```

**Validation Directive**

```
app.directive('myValidationDirective', function(myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                //first, assume validity
                ctrl.$setValidity('myValidationDirective', true);

                //only check if value is not empty
                if(viewValue.length > 0 && !ctrl.$error.myValidationDirective) {
                    myService.getdetailsofField(viewValue).then(function(response){
                        //api returns response.data
                        if(response.data.success === false) {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('myValidationDirective', false);
                            scope.callAScopeFunction(response.data);
                        } else {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('myValidationDirective', true);
                        }
                    }).catch(function(response){
                        //error
                    });
                }
                return viewValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I can look into using a validation directive like you've laid out but the problem is changing ng-model-options to updateOn blur destroys the typeahead action. I will update to show the typeahead